# Record-triggered flow: sending an email 1 hour after a field value is set/changed

Tags: email, visual-workflow

I have a requirement to implement sending an e-mail one hour after the custom field is set to a certain value. What would be the possible approaches to achieve this on Salesforce?

I was thinking of creating a scheduled flow, but I don't know if I can set it properly that way (the e-mail shouldn't be sent at certain time every day but only an hour after the field value change). And I'm not sure if I can use the record-triggered flow, because I must set it to trigger on record creation, but like I said the mail should be sent after a field value is changed. What about process builder?

Answer (score 5):

[Scheduled Paths](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/03/schedule-your-path-in-salesforce-flow) within Flows should work fine. It can be scheduled to occur x amount of time after a record update which is the scenario you'd be interested in.

1. Create a Record-Triggered Flow
2. Select your object and you can set your entry conditions to only happen when that field is that value (if there's no other logic needed in this flow). Otherwise, you can do this in a decision element later if you need other logic in this.

[image]

3. Trigger the flow when `a record is updated`
4. Optimize the Flow for `Actions and Related Records`
5. Click `Add Scheduled Paths (Optional)`
6. Create a path where the time source is `When Object is Updated` and the offset to match your requirements (1 hour after).

[image]

7. Add a Send Email element to your flow.
8. When you connect to that element, you can select a scheduled path. Pick the one you created so the email action occurs 1 hour after the object is updated to meet your criteria.

[image]

With that, you now have logic that runs when the record is updated to meet your criteria (field equals certain value), it will send an email 1 hour after that specific update.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hello martian975 and welcome to Salesforce StackExchange.

Yes, you can use Salesforce Flow to schedule an email to be sent after X amount of time of a change, check the [considerations](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_considerations_trigger_schedule.htm&type=5) & [this post](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/03/schedule-your-path-in-salesforce-flow) that explains how to use the Scheduled Path.

I also suggest you check [Record-Triggered Automation decision guide](https://architect.salesforce.com/design/decision-guides/trigger-automation/) for more in-depth choices regarding automation.

Note: Process builder will be deprecated and we should use flows.